# OpenRefine: Inverting a regular expression

Tags: regex, openrefine

I've seen some questions about inverting regular expressions, but I couldn't apply the solutions to OpenRefine and get it to work.

For instance, suppose I have a zip code field where most of the entries have the form

```
^\d{5}-\d{4}$
```

I want to filter OUT all those entries to see what is left over using GREL regex. How do I create a regular expression that finds all strings without the above form in Openrefine?

Comment: Does your engine support negative look ahead?

Comment: OpenRefine incorporates Java.Util.regex, so I would assume it supports negative lookaheads.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use negative lookarounds as a way to match something **without** a certain substring. In your case it would match everything without 5 digits followed by a dash followed by 4 digits.

`^((?!\d{5}-\d{4}).)*$`

Another work-around to match everything without a certain substring is to simply replace that substring with `""`, and then grab all the entries.

Comment: This works great! Thanks. Is there a way to modify it to return only non-null entries (that also don't match the pattern)?

Comment: Glad it works, you can replace the `*` with a `+`, and that should also ignore all non-null entries.

Comment: Pardon, can you show how you can use the replacement with a regex? What is wrong in this [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LPhny.png) i.e. `replace(value,^((?!\d{5}-\d{4}).)*$,"")`?